# Laravel query where field is less than sum of another field in related table (polymorphic relationship)

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

In Laravel trying to query a table for invoices (table name: `invoices`) where the invoice total (field name: `net_total`) is greater than the sum of payments made for that invoice. It is set as a polymorphic relationship.

Invoice Table:

```
public function transactions(){
    return $this->morphMany(TransactionAllocation::class, 'doc');
}
```

Payment Table:

```
public function doc()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I tried the query which does not seem to work.

```
Invoice::with('transactions')
        ->where('net_total', '>' ,'transactions.amount')
        ->get();
```

I tried the following as per an answer below which gives me sum of relationship but the where condition fails

```
Invoice::withSum('transactions', 'amount')
                    ->where('net_total','>','transactions_sum_amount')
                    ->get();
```

Screenshot of result - https://prnt.sc/1favj7u
The second array shouldn't have comes as it fails where condition.

Any advice on what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you will have many transactions as you said, that is the part missing in the query.

You can try something with [withSum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) for example

```
InvoiceTest::withSum('transactions', 'amount')
    ->havingRaw('transactions_sum_amount < invoices.net_total')
    ->get();
```

Comment: this works in bringing the sum.  But it does not satisfy the where condition. It brings in lines where the sum of net_total is less than or equal to the sum as well.

Comment: ok, so `transactions_sum_amount` this part is fine, maybe you there it 2 `net_total` fields `->where('invoices.net_total', '>' ,'transactions_sum_amount')`

Comment: nope, it does not work either. Here is a screenshot of the results. First one is right. But the second one should not have come.
 https://prnt.sc/1favj7u

Comment: @Thaha use  ->whereColumn('net_total', '>' ,'transactions_sum_amount')

Comment: @JohnLobo it throws this error. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'transactions_sum_amount' in 'where clause

Comment: in the image, the values are strings, are you using a mutator? in the db types are number base?

Comment: Nope, it is saved as number. I can do where with > and < on net_total column alone. That works. Its just where condition does not work with - 'transactions_sum_amount'

Comment: @Thaha try `->having()` instead of `->where()`, it should be running on _group by_

Comment: tried no vain. Now I am trying to create a join and compare. But join doesn't seem to work for polymorphic relationship

Comment: @Thaha just ran a few tests that one is working.

Comment: `->where('invoices.net_total', '>' ,'transactions_sum_amount')` worked for me. Thanks @JuanEizmendi